# Need to stylize area tag inside map

Tags: css

I have image and areas located inside

```
<map name="number_areas">
    <area href="#" shape="poly" coords="190,1,285,1,285,95,190,94" id="area6">
    ....
```

Is there way to set css styles for area tag, like background, transparency etc?

Comment: This might help (uses a plugin though): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969836/how-change-image-map-area-element-style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't possible with css to change assign style to area directly.
Another way is to use SVG file

Here's an example I whipped up: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tZKuv/3/).

in the example you have this css that can make a style to your svg:

```
polygon.hoverable
{
    fill: transparent;
    stroke:gray; /* Replace with none if you like */
    stroke-width: 4;
    cursor: pointer;
}

polygon.hoverable:hover
{
 stroke:black;   
}
```

Other way is to use some plugin in javascript/jQuery like this:

[ImageMapster](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/)